# S3 bucket with credentials error

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

I'm having trouble using the meteor slingshot component with the `S3 with temporary AWS Credentials` component. I keep getting the error `Exception while invoking method 'slingshot/uploadRequest' InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. If I use slingshot normally without credentials it works fine.

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import moment from 'moment';
const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var sts = new AWS.STS();

Slingshot.createDirective('UserProfileResumeUpload', Slingshot.S3Storage.TempCredentials, {
  bucket: 'mybuckname', // change this to your s3's bucket name
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
  acl: 'private',

  temporaryCredentials: Meteor.wrapAsync(function (expire, callback) {
    //AWS dictates that the minimum duration must be 900 seconds:
    var duration = Math.max(Math.round(expire / 1000), 900);

    sts.getSessionToken({
        DurationSeconds: duration
    }, function (error, result) {
        callback(error, result && result.Credentials);
    });
  }),

  authorize: function () {
    //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      const message = 'Please login before posting files';
      throw new Meteor.Error('Login Required', message);
    }

    return true;
  },

  key: function () {
    return 'mydirectory' + '/' + cryptoRandomString(10) + moment().valueOf();
  }
});
```

Path: `Settings.json`

```
{
  "AWSAccessKeyId": "myAWSKEYID",
  "AWSSecretAccessKey": "MyAWSSeceretAccessKey"
}
```

Comment: Re-check that you dont have space in your credentials. I have done that once, and took hours to figure it out.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not picking up my AWS `AWSAccessKeyId` or  `AWSSecretAccessKey`. Am I missing something in my code that would tell it to find them in my settings.json file

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in server side like this :

```
Slingshot.createDirective("UserProfileResumeUpload", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  AWSAccessKeyId: Meteor.settings.AWS.AccessKeyId,
  AWSSecretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.AWS.SecretAccessKey,
  bucket: 'mybuckname', // change this to your s3's bucket name
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
  acl: 'private',
  ...
}
```

and in settings.json

```
{
"AWS":  {
  "AccessKeyId": "myAWSKEYID",
  "SecretAccessKey": "MyAWSSeceretAccessKey" 
 }
}
```

Comment: you should provide full part of the code so i can reproduce the problem

Comment: @bp123 why you are using  Slingshot.S3Storage.TempCredentials temp credentials?

Comment: @liro that's what the documentation says to use if you're using authentication with the bucket. See https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/blob/master/README.md#s3-with-temporary-aws-credentials-advanced

Comment: @bp123 yes for extra security, but did you try without ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Without it works fine but I need the extra security.

Comment: Could it be that temp credentials are too old. Can you  check the source code and see what it tries  to send?

Comment: sorry, do you want me to console.log `var sts = new AWS.STS();`?