# InvalidClientTokenId when using IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm having trouble implementing `GetCallerIdentity` with AWS within my application. When I try to generate *temporary credentials*, the server console returns the error `InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid`.

I've been looking at the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) and I'm wondering if I've set up my IAM user incorrectly. The documentation says;

The temporary security credentials created by GetSessionToken can be used to make API calls to any AWS service with the following exceptions:

- You cannot call any IAM APIs unless MFA authentication information is
  included in the request.
- You cannot call any STS API except AssumeRole or GetCallerIdentity.

Does this mean I can't use IAM accounts with the below example? I'm building in meteor js and I'm trying to implement a package called [SlingShot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot#s3-with-temporary-aws-credentials-advanced). The documentation doesn't mention errors like this.

```
var sts = new AWS.STS();

sts.getSessionToken({
  DurationSeconds: duration
}, function (error, result) {
  console.log('error', error);
  callback(error, result && result.Credentials);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more details and more source code to what you are doing? I don't understand the part where you say "I'm wondering if I've set up my IAM user incorrectly". Also, you need to include SerialNumber and TokenCode when you call getSessionToken.

Comment: The source code I'm trying to implement, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619756/s3-bucket-with-credentials-error?noredirect=1#comment84260903_48619756

Comment: The slingshot component 'see link in post `doesn't mention SerialNumber or TokenCode so I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Review the documentation for the APIs that you call so that you understand. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have read it multiple times and I'm not getting anywhere. If I `console.log(sts)` it return `Service {
config: 
Config {
credentials: 
SharedIniFileCredentials {
expired: false,
expireTime: null,
accessKeyId: 'AKeyIsHere',
sessionToken: undefined,
filename: undefined,
profile: 'default',
disableAssumeRole: true },
......` I assume this means it has connected.

Comment: the `console.log(sts)` doesn't contain a `getSessionToken`. Is it suppose to?

Comment: Make sure that you are not using an out of date SDK. I have never used console.log(sts) so I don't know the answer. Follow the documentation otherwise you will always be chasing issues. Plus there are lots of examples to study on the Internet.